# How to ignore case when comparing string?

Tags: c#

I am using linq to search through a list (user enters query in a textbox).

I want this to be case-insensitive and tried to use IgnoreCase, but I have no idea where to put it.... I know I could use upper or lower, but I would like to hear if anybody has any alternative methods? What would be considered best practise?
Regex did not seem to work either?

```
        string searchQuery = tbSearchQuery.Text;
        var something= from x in y 
                       where x.Subject.Contains(searchQuery)
                       select x;
```

Comment: It actually kinda depends on what the `y` is here... i.e. is this LINQ-to-Objects? -SQL? -EF? Different implementation will support different things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [string.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx):

```
    var something= from x in y 
                   where string.Compare(x.Subject, searchQuery, true) >= 0
                   select x;
```

This can also handle situations where either strings are null.

Comment: I don't know why this is accepted -- it is not the correct answer. This code returns all strings that are either equal to or have a higher *sort order* than the query. It returns "Bill" when the query is "Adam". This would only be useful if you were checking for `== 0`, which would return only equal strings, but a) `Equals` would be better for that; and b) the question is about returning strings that *contain* the query, not only those that exactly match.

Comment: String.Compare works for its intended purpose, which is *determining relative sort order*, but the question is about looking for matches from a search query. My comment was not a bogus claim: [see the output for yourself](http://ideone.com/CTTtgM) (at the bottom). Those results are incorrect because the user did not search for anything resembling "Bill" or "Charlie". It also *should* have returned "1adam", but it doesn't. [Dylan Smith's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7804593/933416) is correct because it passes the test successfully: [see the correct output here](http://ideone.com/fCml5p).

Comment: It doesn't work.  As nmclean said, it works if you use " == 0" but returns too many results when you use the " >= 0"

Answer (score 7):

Since nobody else has put it up yet, I'd propose using the static [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) so you don't have to worry about `null` and get back only the information you want.

[String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) also works but you're not trying to sort the strings (the reason for the integer return value), just determine whether they are value-equal under case-insensitive comparison.

```
var something = from x in y 
                where string.Equals(x.Subject, searchQuery, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                select x;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string searchQuery = tbSearchQuery.Text; 
var something= from x in y  
               where x.Subject.IndexOf(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
               select x;
```

Comment: the original question was not about EF.  Depending on your DB settings string compares are usually case in-sensitive by default, so you can use the original code in the question and it should work fine for EF.

Comment: Right, was just letting others know since I saw an upvoted comment.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following own made extensions (for plain strings)

```
 public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
 {
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
 }

 public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string toCheck)
 {
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
 }
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string searchQuery = tbSearchQuery.Text; 
var something= from x in y  
               where x.Subject.IndexOf(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
```

Comment: Well, you can add a null check to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `IndexOf` instead?

```
string searchQuery = tbSearchQuery.Text;
var something= from x in y 
               where x.Subject.IndexOf(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
               select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LINQ-to-SQL` or `Entity Framework`, the collation rules are fixed and set in the table definition. The only way to compare them is to `ToUpper` (or `ToLower`, but it's better to `ToUpper` as written here http://www.siao2.com/2007/10/01/5218976.aspx) both part of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I second the extension method way.  I've got a class I use.  Just plonk it in your project and reference YOUR NAME SPACE and away you go.

```
using System;

namespace YOUR NAME SPACE
{
    public static class StringExtensionMethods
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extention method to allow a string comparison where you can supply the comparison type 
        /// (i.e. ignore case, etc).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The compare string.</param>
        /// <param name="comparisionType">The comparison type - enum, use OrdinalIgnoreCase to ignore case.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the string is present within the original string.    </returns>
        public static bool Contains(this string original, string value, StringComparison comparisionType)
        {
            return original.IndexOf(value, comparisionType) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example of a LINQ query using it:

```
var results = from promotion in response
              where
                  String.IsNullOrEmpty(find.Code) ||
                  (promotion.Code != null && promotion.Code.Contains(find.Code, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              where
                  String.IsNullOrEmpty(find.Name) ||
                  (promotion.Name != null && promotion.Name.Contains(find.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              select promotion;
```