# ToUpper() in lambda not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

```
var Result = addressContext.Address_Lookup
                 .Where(c => c.Address_Full.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()) 
                          || c.Address_Full.ToUpper().Contains(TermModified.ToUpper()))
                 .Select(e => new { 
                                 id = e.Address_ID, 
                                 label = e.Address_Full, 
                                 value = e.Address_Full })
                 .ToList();
```

To ensure search will be non-case sensitive I am using `ToUpper()`.
I am searching for something like Jimmy (with a capital J).  jimmy (all lower case) doesnt catch? why?

Comment: `.ToUpper` cannot be translated to SQL function. In this case, string comparison type will depend on database collation.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: On the contrary, [it can be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738681(v=vs.100).aspx). It depends on the query provider, but EF specifically should easily do this... no idea why it doesn't.

Comment: Does it work with any of the other approaches? Can you show us your collation settings as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804539/how-to-ignore-case-when-comparing-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using entity-framework, a linq-to-sql framework, you're actually trying to make the database perform a `.ToUpper` rather than performing one in-memory as you would if running through an `IEnumerable`. If the query translation in your framework doesn't support the function, it either won't be used or throw an Exception.

You can generally predict such behaviour by checking whether you're calling a function against an `IQueryable` object, which queues all calls as an expression tree for translation, or an `IEnumerable`, which uses `foreach` and `yield return`s to handle evaluation. Since the Linq functions are extension methods, polymorphism doesn't apply here.

If you're not worried about the performance hit of getting EVERY entry from that table in-memory, add a `.AsEnumerable()` call, and your functionwill evaluate on localized data.

```
var Result = addressContext.Address_Lookup
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Where(c => c.Address_Full.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()) 
         || c.Address_Full.ToUpper().Contains(TermModified.ToUpper()))
     .Select(e => new
     { 
         id = e.Address_ID, 
         label = e.Address_Full, 
         value = e.Address_Full
     })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: "If the query translation in your framework doesn't support the function, it won't be used at best, and crash at worst." You might want to switch around the labeling of your best and worst cases. It would be pretty horrid if the system silently ignored the ToUpper part. ;)

Comment: I think crashing versus silently failing is a matter of opinion - so I'll remove both labels ;3

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer, for some reason still no go?